# A 5 pointed riddle

Tags: riddle

Ask me for directions and I will point in 5 directions
Stop me pointing, I am vermin reincarnated
I may be nocturnal and prefer the dark
But stop and look where my first point points
You'll see me out shining bright
Mix and add 19 and 20 and you're back where it starts
But just remember I know what you like

Comment: is it possibly a star?

Comment: possibly, ill need some reasons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask me for directions and I will point in 5 directions

> A five-pointed star?

Stop me pointing, I am vermin reincarnated

> Turned around, STAR becomes RATS

I may be nocturnal and prefer the dark

> Most often, you can only see the stars at night

But stop and look where my first point points
You'll see me out shining bright

> The top point of a star points either *up* or *North*, skyward (where stars, including but not limited to *the Sun*, are seen) or to the north star.

Mix and add 19 and 20 and you're back where it starts

> the 19th and 20th letters are S and T; mix them and add to the end and you've got STARTS

But just remember I know what you like

> On a number of websites as well as in real life, you can use a star to indicate that you like something (Here on Puzzling, it's right below the voting buttons; on Twitter it was the indicator for a Favorite, but has been replaced by the heart)

Comment: give this man the correct answer and call it a day

Comment: @DemonicBirdFlu It might not be right! I still don't know what the last line means, and I'm not even totally sure about the 2nd-to-last

Comment: 1 + 4 + 1 + 5 = 11. A star has 10 vertices... if you visit each vertex and continue to the first you have visited 11 vertices.

Comment: @GeorgeReith I'm a little confused by this - where is the 11 coming from (that is, aside from your equation and your explanation)?

Comment: @question_asker You count the first one twice because you go back to the start

Comment: @GeorgeReith Oh! (incidentally that was the part I understood, I just didn't get where you were pulling those numbers from at first)

Comment: @GeorgeReith why must you count the first one twice? you can just start at the first point and not count it yet.

Comment: @DemonicBirdFlu you could... or you could count it as a visit. Who knows it's just a suggestion. 0 indexed vs 1 indexed there's no right or wrong.

Comment: Sorry with the 14 and 15 bit it is wrong ill edit

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil OK, got that part now

Comment: Correct! The second to last is close enough, I meant it points up to the sky where the stars are but your idea is close

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil OK, also got the very last one

Comment: Well done! This was probably too easy